# Python argument to provide less-like limiting functionality

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

Any idea if there is a *clean* way to make `optparse` bypass/handle a generic `-XXX` option ?

My case is an application for which i want to provide a `less` like option to limit the application s output entries to the number defined after `-`

e.g.

```
myapp.py list -10
```

i guess i could overwrite `sys.argv` dict to avoid `optparse` from raising an error and manually parse/remove the custom argument, but i'm wondering if this is a case that optparse lib foresees and provides a better way to do it.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at `argparse` instead.

Comment: +1 for `argparse`, which makes this easy. Doing this in `optparse` requires you to create a custom `Option` class and a custom `OptionParser` class. Even then, it's tricky to distinguish option clusters from these "bare" options (for example, does `myapp.py list -10` mean `myapp.py list -1 -0` (optparse's default) or `-10`?

Comment: thanks for the comments, how can i achieve it with argparse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In argparse, you can define an optional positional integer argument. Negative values will then look to the user like giving an option:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('limit', type=int, nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.limit is not None:
    print "Limiting to %d." % -args.limit
```

The default help text is not reasonable in this case, but can be adjusted with the `metavar` keyword argument to `add_argument`, using e.g. `"-n"`.

I can only come up with a nasty looking way to do this with optparse. Basically define an individual option for each digit that the number can start with:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-1")
parser.add_option("-2")
options,args = parser.parse_args()
if options.__dict__["1"] is not None:
    print "Your number was %d." % (int("1"+options.__dict__["1"]))
elif options.__dict__["2"] is not None:
    print "Your number was %d." % (int("2"+options.__dict__["2"]))
```

and so on for all digits up to 9. Also think about whether 0 needs to be considered...

Comment: nasty indeed :), plus its limited since in my case i want the number to be 1 to infinite

Comment: Well, the number can be up to (but excluding) infinity. You just need options for 1 - 9, the rest of the digits is taken from the option argument.